# PyQt Widget Won't Show Until Introducing Tkinter

Tags: qt, tkinter, pyqt

My company have developed a QT based software. It calls python script with a cmd process on Win10. The widget won't show when I call the PyQt script. And the weird thing is that the window shows up if I add a Tkinter object. What's going on?

```
def show_demo(text):
    # The window won't show util adding this
    # window = Tk()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please show the code.  Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Your code works fine in my Window 10 running Python 3.8.2 and PyQt5 5.14.2.

Comment: Thank u  @acw1668! But the difference is that my PyQt was called by C++ QT with cmd. I don't know if they confict somehow.

Comment: @FranklinTao provide a [mre]

Comment: How do you call the script in _C++ QT with cmd_?